# Pen testing, Windows: Using credentials to impersonate users from SYSTEM

Tags: windows, penetration-test, metasploit, active-directory, programming

Following simple scenario during pen test:

- I have remote code execution on a windows box and am SYSTEM (either because of the way I got onto the box or because of the persistence method I chose)
- I got my hands on local or domain credentials I want to use (as in: have a remote shell as that guy).
- no user is logged in (if one was loggend in, and there was no protection software, I could inject into one of their processes. Yes, bad idea, very noisy.)

Now windows runas.exe does not even start, metasploit runas does not work, empire runas / spawnas does not work, because I am SYSTEM in session 0. As I understand it, the latter two do fairly naìve LogonUser() => CreateProcessAsUser(). I cannot even spawn an process as local Admin that way, even though I have his credentials.

My uninformed guess is you would need to do more involved magic (worst case create a new desktop session. E.g. the RDP service runs as system and does use my credentials to create fully functional processes as me).

Currently the only way I see is a multiday journey into windows internals and writing my own implant or metasploit railgun module. But this problem must have been solved, ms08_067 was 10 years ago.

How do I properly go from SYSTEM to DOMAIN\joe or .\jane if I have the credentials?

Comment: Can you just use the credentials to log in remotely or use psexec over SMB?

Comment: Not what I asked. Yes, of course, if I have admin creds for another machine and I am sure there is no monitoring or protection software, I can do a psexec style service creation which gives me rce as SYSTEM on another box.

Comment: Of course you are right, that there are always fun things you can do if what you want does not work. So Why would I want to become a user? For example, I can run the local sqlplus.exe to interact with the local db. Or I can do an easy dcsync if the user has that right.

Comment: Think CreateProcessWithLogonW with the LOGON_WITH_PROFILE might do what you need it to. Unsure of any tools that use this, maybe try a GitHub search.